# Help with getting two different data types from IEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have `IEnumerable` object with value1 and value2. value2 is an array and value1 is string.
I want to databind this object to Listview like that. So both value1 and value2[0] (always first item in array) could be accessed via `<%# Eval("value1") %>` and `<%# Eval("value2") %>` .

How to write expression to handle both items ?

```
    ListViewItems.DataSource = f.Items.Select(t => t.value1, t.value2[0]);
    ListViewItems.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create an anonymous type:

```
ListViewItems.DataSource = f.Items.Select(
    t => new { Value1 = t.value1, Value2 = t.value2[0] }
);
```